# Using destructoring in JS to assemble a new object could not be done in TS - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I want to use destructoring to create a new object from an existing one.

In JS i do the following:

```js
const objOrig = { a: 1, b:2, c: 3};
const objChanged = { ...({a, c} = objOrig), ...{b:'S'} };
// => objChanged is: { a: 1, b: 'S', c: 3 }
```

If I want to do the same with TS I get:
TS18004: No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'a'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.

```
type S = {a: number; b: number| string; c: number};
const objOrig: S = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
const objChanged: S = { ...({a, c} = objOrig), ...{b:'S'} }
```

If TS is realy a superset of JS, then it should be possible, so: what am i doing wrong?

([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAylC8UDeBDAXFAdgVwLYCMIAnAbinwxwOIB8oBnYIgS0wHMyBjSvQogXxIAoTgHtMjKKPwArAPIs2GOIiRR0UAIwAachgBMu7lADMgkeMnSZAYQAWKdhAAmyhMigA6bwApUR-ndrBWY2AEpdb08kCgByGFjA-iA))

Comment: TS is a superset in the sense that all JavaScript programs are **syntactically valid** TypeScript programs. It doesn't mean all JavaScript programs will be valid TypeScript programs.

Comment: Your code isn't even valid JS in strict mode: `a` and `c` are implicit global variables. TS assumes strict mode. That's what the error is trying to tell you: you don't initialize `a`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your JS code is that it's actually declaring two global variables, `a` and `c`:

```js
const objOrig = { a: 1, b:2, c: 3};
const objChanged = { ...({a, c} = objOrig), ...{b:'S'} };

console.log(a, c);
console.log(objChanged);
```

Turn on strict mode and see that it fails in JavaScript:

```js
"use strict";

const objOrig = { a: 1, b:2, c: 3};
const objChanged = { ...({a, c} = objOrig), ...{b:'S'} };
```

The correct way to change the object is this:

```
const objChanged: S = { ...objOrig, ...{ b:'S' } }
```

but since there is only one property being changed, you can simplify to:

```
const objChanged: S = { ...objOrig, b:'S' }
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WylrAm)

Answer (score 0):

As vera said, the JS code is easy to misunderstand.

Perhaps I have kept the example too simple. The objChanged should also be a different TS type.

I was able to solve my problem as follows.

```
    // TS-code 
    type S1 = { a: number; b: number; c: number };
    type S2 = { a: number; b: string; c: number };

    const origObj: S1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
    let a: S1['a'];
    let c: S1['c'];
    const otherObj: S2 = { ...(({ a, c } = origObj), { a, c }), ...{ b: 'S2' } };

    console.log(`origObj: ${JSON.stringify(origObj)}\notherObj: ${JSON.stringify(otherObj)}`);
```

Thanks again for the replies.